# Cherry Tree - Bark peeled back and with bug holes

Tags: fruit-trees, bugs, cherries

I've only had this cherry tree for a little over 2 years now. The bark started to peel back near the ground. After a couple branches lost all their leaves I knew something was wrong - I looked where the bark had peeled back and it appears like some bugs are digging holes in it now. I'm living in the Sacramento, CA region too in case that matters. (the wood ash around it is something I just put there a couple days ago to stop the squirrels from burying nuts).

Trying to figure out if there's anything I can do to save it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like borer damage. They are difficult to control as they are in the wood. Some can be killed by pushing a wire into the holes if the holes are relatively straight.The tree does not look good.

Comment: I did try sticking wire into the holes... didn't seem to do anything... tried it from several different angles. At most it would go in an inch, but most didn't even go in that far. What about pruning paint... worth a shot or pointless?

Comment: An open hole means the moth has left - too late to poke with wire.

Comment: Sometimes they are still in the hole; especially if you see fresh sawdust around it.